# Refactoring Interactive Leaflet Map using Typescript not possible

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, leaflet, refactoring

I'm building a simple SPA using Angular, Leaflet and @types/leaflet.
I've been following the leaflet guide on how to setup an interactive Map,
which you can see here [Interactive Map Tutorial](https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/).
Till now I added functionally to highlight hovering over features and zoom on click.

```js
export class MapOverviewComponent implements OnInit {
  map: Map | undefined;
  
   geoJsonLayer: GeoJSON | undefined;
   southWestBounds: LatLngTuple = [-90, -200];
   northEastBounds: LatLngTuple = [90, 200];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const style: PathOptions = {
      color: '#FE6D73',
      weight: 2,
      opacity: 1,
      dashArray: '3',
      fillOpacity: 0.7
  };
  this.map = new Map('map', {
    maxBounds: new LatLngBounds(this.southWestBounds, this.northEastBounds),
    minZoom: 3,
    maxZoom: 7
  }).setView([20, 0], 2);
    this.geoJsonLayer = new GeoJSON(geoJsonData as GeoJSON.GeoJsonObject, {
      style: style,
      onEachFeature: (feature: GeoJSON.Feature<GeoJSON.Geometry, GeoJSON.GeoJsonProperties>, layer: Layer) => {
        layer.on({
          mouseover: (event: LeafletMouseEvent) => {
            const layer = event.target;
            layer.setStyle({
                weight: 5,
                color: '#666',
                dashArray: '3',
                fillOpacity: 0.7,
            });
        
            layer.bringToFront();
          },
          mouseout: (event: LeafletMouseEvent) => {
            this.geoJsonLayer?.resetStyle(event.target);
          },
          click: (event: LeafletMouseEvent) => {
            this.map?.fitBounds(event.target.getBounds());
          }
        });
      } 
    }).addTo(this.map);
  }
}
```

Everything i want is working fine, but I've been trying to refactor this thing, but it does not let me. Moving out the geoJsonLayer and Map out of the OnInit was no problem, but when i try to create seperate functions for the EventHandlers inside the onEachFeature, the event handlers get called when initialized and seem to initialize fine, but do not trigger on the specified action.

Example - Moved EventHandler Function:

```js
  onClick(event: LeafletMouseEvent) {
     this.map?.fitBounds(event.target.getBounds());
  }
```

New Call inside onEachFeature:

```js
  click: this.onClick
```

Is this a limit of the leaflet library in combination with @types/leaflet or something else?

Comment: Inspect the value of `this` when the code in `forEachFeature` runs.

Comment: @IvanSanchez Right. The Arrow Function preserves my outer (class) context, whereas by calling a function it gives me the GeoJSON context. Thanks